# What does the number of key animators and inbetweeners depend on?

Tags: anime-production, violet-evergarden, sora-yori-mo-tooi-basho

As I watch more anime I kind of noticed this: some ok-looking shows have a lot of animators while other really good-looking shows don't.

For example, Violet Evergarden and Sora yori mo Tooi Basho are two shows from Winter 2018, and the number of key animators and inbetweeners differ so much.

Violet Evergarden Episode 1:

[image] [image]

9 key animators + 4 inbetweeners

Sora yori mo Tooi Basho Episode 1:

[image] [image]

28 key animators + 14 inbetweeners

Why does Violet Evergarden have so few key animators and yet is so gorgeous looking? Sora yori mo Tooi Basho on the other hand, has simpler character designs and visuals. Wouldn't the latter take fewer people to draw? What could be possible reasons for this?

Comment: This somehow relates to the fact that Kyoto Animation does everything in house, while other studios mostly outsource from many freelancers making the number of animators and other positions higher

Comment: Quality of the work output depends on a lot more factors than how much manpower are put over a task. Some studios outsource a lot of work to china, some have ideologies and standards that they hold themselves to, some even trains their animators extensively.

Comment: It also depends on how much time they spend per episode, the tighter the schedule the more artists you need to get everything done in time.